# Why does my tqdm progress bar display on a new line for every iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, tqdm

I'm working on a personal project where I grab data from a website using requests. One of the files is quite large so I wanted to include a progress bar as a "sign of life".

The downloading bit works but the progress bar constantly outputs on a new line even though I've based it on the examples from the tqdm docs.

Code below:

```py
def download_data() -> BinaryIO:
    """Download the two zipped data packages
    from the Open Power System Data website.

    Returns
    -------
    BinaryIO
        Saves the two packages in Data/Raw
    """
    urls = [GENERATION_CAPACITY_URL, TIME_SERIES_URL]

    for url in urls:
        # Gets the filename directly from the url, saves us having to name it
        url_filename = Path(urlparse(url).path).name

        # Check if exists before doing lengthy download
        if not Path.exists(RAW_DATA / url_filename):

            # Stream = True because files are quite large
            with requests.get(url, stream=True) as response:

                # Check connection first, will raise HTTPError if bad
                response.raise_for_status()

                chunk_size = 1024 * 1024

                print(f"Downloading {url_filename}")

                with open(RAW_DATA / url_filename, "wb") as f:
                    with tqdm(
                        unit="B",
                        unit_scale=True,
                        unit_divisor=1024,
                        total=int(response.headers.get("content-length", 0)),
                    ) as pbar:

                        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
                            f.write(chunk)
                            pbar.update(len(chunk))

        else:
            print(f"File: {url_filename} already exists")
```

I call the function below in a name == main condition (not shown for clarity)

When I run the file I get a progress bar that updates as the file downloads, but each update seems to render a new progress bar on a new line rather than one permanent progress bar where the bar just moves along the screen (as you'd expect)

i.e. instead of:

```sh
[|||||| 3%]
```

I get

```sh
[| 1%]
[| 1%]
[|| 2%]
[||| 3%]
```

On and on until it finishes.

Not sure if I'm doing something basic wrong, I just can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `leave=True` keyword

with tqdm(unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024, total=int(response.headers.get("content-length", 0)),**leave=True**) as pbar: